# Cannot alter column due it is part of the partition key

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I want to alter a column in the base table SysLog from type "timestamp without time zone"
to "timestamp with time zone" due Npgsql 6.0 with this MigrationBuilder command:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "Inserted",
                table: "SysLog",
                type: "timestamp with time zone",
                nullable: true,
                oldClrType: typeof(DateTime),
                oldType: "timestamp without time zone",
                oldNullable: true);
```

Error message: `Npgsql.PostgresException: '42P16: cannot alter column "Created" because it is part of the partition key of relation "SysLog"'`

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I suspect you may need to recreate the table in order to alter a column that's part of the partition key. You can add [raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#adding-raw-sql) into the migration which creates the new table, copies the data across (`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`), and then deletes the old table and renames the new one in its place.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your table has patritioning configured for column "Created". This prevents from changing the column type.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html

You would have to remove partitioning before changning column type.
Or copy table, change type and rename it.